# C++ vector lower and upper bound check

Tags: c++, vector, std, stdvector, indexoutofboundsexception

I use `[]` for accessing vectors in math code. I don't want to use `at()` because I don't like exceptions. I am happy explicitly checking bounds in the code when I am not sure of my indices. So, my code is full of statements of this sort: `if(n >= 0 && n < vec.size())`.

My question is, I have not found in `std::vector` a call like `vec.isok(n)` which directly says if *yes* or *no* an index is in bounds.

Have I overlooked it? it would make for much neater code in my case.

By the way, the explicit checking is also I think more efficient than an `at()` call because typically I am using nested vector structures and when I check an index `n` once, I then use `n` many times inside the `if` bracket, sometimes thousands of times. So, my question is, do you see a neater way of doing this without two tests in the `if`. Thanks!

Comment: it is always nice to read such wall of text

Comment: Please highlight and format your future questions. Otherwise they are hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `std::vector` has not such a thing like `std::vector::isOK(x)`. You can warp `std::vector` in your `SafeVector` and publish the safe interfaces to use.

Comment: Alternatively, just add a free-standing function `vectorIndexOk` or similar.

Comment: see [this implementation](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CF0QFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpetrov.stanford.edu%2Fsoftware%2Fsrc%2Fprobcons%2FSafeVector.h&ei=ZqBgU8XSLdDzyAPgwID4Bg&usg=AFQjCNEFiklh71tNF1pOh2YHFT6bz1ri3Q&sig2=Ckr42ncTKN7Ll9OhCGNeLg&bvm=bv.65636070,d.bGQ) if you need a reference.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way:

```
template <typename T>
inline bool isok(const std::vector<T>& vec,
                 typename std::vector<T>::size_type index)
{
    return index >= 0 && index < vec.size();
}
```

then call it as `isok(vec, i)`

Comment: Isn't the check for ">= 0" irrelevant? Or are there implementations where `size_type` is *not* unsigned?

Comment: @lethal-guitar That's a good point, I thought `size_type` could be signed but apparently the docs specify that will always be unsigned (in which case I suspect the compiler would get rid of the check anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can have your own implementation of accessing the index of a vector. And in that function of yours you can use these checks (one time investment) and use this function for accessing later on. But again, even if you use this function, you still need to worry about what it returns in case of an out of bound index.

You can also go for some other data structure. If these items can have keys(any unique identifier), you can go for a map.